# Alternativa C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, hospedagem

Olá,
Tenho alguns windows services escritos em C# (Framework 4.0) rodando em servidor aqui na empresa, esses serviços realizam algumas monitorações para deixar informações disponíveis para quando o usuário se logar no sistema asp.net.

Deixaremos de utilizar o servidor interno para utilizar uma hospedagem externa, existe alguma alternativa para os windows services serem hospedados, porque nessas hospedagens externas não é possível instalar um windows service. A princípio utilizaremos o UOL Host mas se alguém  sugerir uma hospedagem melhor agradeço.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês.

Grata

Comment: Depende das tarefas e recursos que esses serviços consomem. Se for apenas banco de dados, talvez você nem precise hospedar eles em um novo ambiente, apenas fazer os apontamentos corretos. Mas se a sua aplicação asp.net depende desses serviços do windows, você deve procurar uma solução de hospedagem mais completa que forneça o ambiente com todos os requisitos que você precisa.

Comment: Tive um caso parecido e simplesmente convertemos os serviços para aplicações Web que rodam no `IIS` e resolvemos o problema. Os serviços eram bem simples, liam pastas e copiavam arquivos além de mandar email, tudo facilmente migrado pra uma aplicação Web, praticamente só copiar e colar

Comment: Esses webservices acessam o banco de dados para armazenar os dados das monitorações e acessam webservices externos para obter os dados de análise. Os serviços ficam rodando 24h, não são "startados" por intervenção de algum usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que descreveu o melhor para o seu cenário é você utilizar um AWS, Azure ou afins, não sei qual a criticidade/tamanho do seu sistema, mas eu fugiria dessas hospedagens "xxxHost" da vida.

Você pode ter a opção de pegar um server, e rodar o que precisa lá dentro, por exemplo:

Sem alterar sua arquitetura eu partiria para um servidor por exemplo um "t2.medium" na AWS. (2 vcpu, 4gb memoria) - Windows
(https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)

Claro que a configuração de hardware depende do tamanho da sua aplicação e afins.

Como opção também tem o **WebJobs**

No Azure você tem os **WebJobs** onde no caso você terá que converter seus serviços para os WebJobs para rodar no Azure.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs